# dbf2mysql not adding table

Tags: mysql, utf-8, dbf

new to stackoverflow.

Building financial models I have a data source that produces legacy dBase III files which I am importing into mysql. They come in a self-extracting `filename.exe` which unrar e `filename.exe` handles nicely. dbf2mysql also works on 10 of the 11 .DBF files that are extracted.

One .DBF in particular I cannot add to the default 'test' db for some reason. All others are fine. Looking at it in MSACCESS it seems that some columns contain strange characters. Wondering if that is causing the .DBF to not add to mysql db 'test'?

I have tried every combination from the `dbf2mysql` man page. A table is never created, and when I create the table manually, nothing is appended.

So, since I don't absolutely require the columns with the strange characters, I have tried to use the -o option to only import 3 columns. No luck.

This is what I have tried repeatedly (without -o)

`$ dbf2mysql -q -vv -c -t test -U msgross -P samaritan FILENM.DBF`

Has anybody successfully used -o to create a table with only selected columns?

Any help is appreciated.  Cheers.

Comment: What "strange characters"?

Comment: they appear to be fractions, but not text like 1/2 or 1/4

Comment: using the dbf2mysql command above with -vv shows that it is processing and adding rows. however, there is no table created in mysql even with the -c -t